# Какой DOCTYPE нужен для верстки e-mail рассылок? (HTML4 или 5)

Tags: html5, вёрстка-email

Причем чтобы нормально отображалось и в почтовых клиентах а-ля Thunderbird и в веб-сервисах. Везде пишут, что 4, но это инфа за 2015-й. Может, уже и на 5 нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для писем наиболее подходящим доктайпом является:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Comment: А я думал везде надо использовать стандарт HTML5 :(